# How to change UIImageView image using SwipeGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Hello everyone I have a `UIViewController` and UIImageView and i have a `SwipeGestureRecognizer` in it. So if the user swipe left or right it will `change` the `UIImageView` image.So far its working. I cannot use  a `UIScrollView` the size of one of the images, with paging enabled.I want to achieve the effect of drag and see part the the next `UIImageView` as in the `UIScrollView` of images would do.

[image]

Comment: so you would like to do image change with swipe instead of scrollview, but with the same "effect" ?

Comment: yes the change image part is working with swipe left or right.Yes i am trying to achieve the same effect as if the images is in a uiscrollview of images when you start dragging you can see part of the  next or previous image

Comment: without UIScrollview you can not expect the effect like UIImage2 needs to come next immediate to UIImage1. But you can change the images based on the swiping using UISwipeGesture Recognozer. For that you need to dynamically bring the images from NSArray images.

Comment: i have been able to change the images.. so no work around to have the same effect as if in a uiscrollview?

Comment: I added an answer veereef, check it

Comment: i didn't get you clearly.. exactly what is your need? Are you need translation of images just using swipe gesture recognizer? or Are you need translation of images with same effect which you showed above using swipe gesture recognizer?

Comment: same effect which I showed above using swipe gesture recognizer but without using a uiscrollview.

Comment: If you benefited from some one answer, feel free to accept....:)

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer :

Add two gesture for the image view and place one count variable, toggle the count variable based on the swipe and no. of the images. Finally change the image based on the count.

Use this code its working fine and simple too.

```
- (void)addAnimationPresentToView:(UIView *)viewTobeAnimated
{
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.30;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    [transition setValue:@"IntroSwipeIn" forKey:@"IntroAnimation"];
    transition.fillMode=kCAFillModeForwards;
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromRight;
    [viewTobeAnimated.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

}

- (void)addAnimationPresentToViewOut:(UIView *)viewTobeAnimated
{
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.30;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    [transition setValue:@"IntroSwipeIn" forKey:@"IntroAnimation"];
    transition.fillMode=kCAFillModeForwards;
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromLeft;
    [viewTobeAnimated.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

}
                - (void)viewDidLoad
                {
                    [super viewDidLoad];
                    count = 0;
                    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
                    [self.imageViewSwipe setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
                    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeRight:)];

                    // Setting the swipe direction.
                    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
                    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

                    // Adding the swipe gesture on image view
                    [self.imageViewSwipe addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
                    [self.imageViewSwipe addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];


                }
                -(void)changeImage
                {
                    switch (count) {
                        case 1:
                            self.imageViewSwipe.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Screen Shot 2013-09-17 at 10.57.51 AM.png"];
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            self.imageViewSwipe.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Screen Shot 2013-09-17 at 10.58.04 AM.png"];
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            self.imageViewSwipe.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Screen Shot 2013-09-17 at 10.58.00 AM.png"];
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                -(void)handleSwipe:(id)sender
                {
                 if(count < 4)
                 {
                     count++;
                     UIImageView *moveIMageView = self.imageViewSwipe;
                     [self addAnimationPresentToView:moveIMageView];
                     [self changeImage];
                 }

                }
                -(void)handleSwipeRight:(id)sender
                {
                    if(count>0)
                    {
                        count--;
                  UIImageView *moveIMageView = self.imageViewSwipe;
                 [self addAnimationPresentToViewOut:moveIMageView];
                        [self changeImage];
                    }

                }
                    -(void)handleSwipe:(id)sender
                    {
                     if(count < 4)
                     {
                         count++;
                         [self changeImage];
                     }

                    }
                    -(void)handleSwipeRight:(id)sender
                    {
                        if(count>0)
                        {
                            count--;
                            [self changeImage];
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: this answer is not good, this will only change the image, not change the image with scrollview effect, so it s not an answer for the question

Comment: Now check animation effect added for both right and left swipe perfect fix.

Answer (score 2):

Add scroollview to mainview(set frame appropriately)

```
[mainview addSubview:scr];
```

write a method like:

```
- (void)setupScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrMain {
}
```

Then in `viewDidLoad` pass scrollview to method,

```
 [self setupScrollView:scr];



- (void)setupScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrMain {
    // we have 10 images here.
    // we will add all images into a scrollView & set the appropriate size.

    for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
        // create image
//        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sti%02i.png",i]];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sti%02i.png",i]];
        // create imageView
//        NSLog(@"===============>%d",i);
        UIImageView *imgV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i-1)*scrMain.frame.size.width, 0, scrMain.frame.size.width, scrMain.frame.size.height)];
        // set scale to fill
        imgV.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        // set image
        [imgV setImage:image];
        // apply tag to access in future
        imgV.tag=i+1;
        // add to scrollView
        [scrMain addSubview:imgV];
    }
    // set the content size to 10 image width
    [scrMain setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrMain.frame.size.width*5, scrMain.frame.size.height)];
    // enable timer after each 2 seconds for scrolling.
    // [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:nil userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

It let you move in both the directions manually.

Comment: scrollview is just to contain the all image frame..you can drag images with same code...try using it and then let me know what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`*`You can try with something imageView.layer to give some animation effect.
`*`

Comment: Hello there thanks for reply .. i am taking a look at animations can you give me an example how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best is use `UIPanGestureRecognizer`:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer * pan1 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveObject:)];
pan1.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
[image1 addGestureRecognizer:pan1];

-(void)moveObject:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan;
{
 image1.center = [pan locationInView:image1.superview];
}
```

when you start dragging check the somehow the direction. if the direction is left to right, add the "before" image to the screen with -image.width , and in the move method, move this imageBefore.center = [pan locationInView:image1.superview]; too. If the direction is right to left, add the "next" image to the scree with +screensize+image.width, and int he move method, move this imageNext.center = [pan locationInView:image1.superview]; too.

I haven't tried this, but i think it should work. I hope it helps

EDIT:

I found for you how to detect the direction:

```
-(void)moveObject:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan;
{

    CGPoint vel = [pan velocityInView:self.view];
    if (vel.x > 0)
    {
        // user dragged towards the right
        counter++;
    }  
    else
    {
        // user dragged towards the left
        counter--;
    }
}
```

Comment: hello thanks i am trying your code .. what is "rec" ? in CGPoint vel = [rec velocityInView:self.view];?

Comment: Hello ok thanks .. can you give me more details on  If the direction is right to left, add the "next" image to the scree with +screensize+image.width, and int he move method, move this imageNext.center = [pan locationInView:image1.superview]; too. .. I didnt get it though :)

Comment: I think that using a Pan Recognizer is the best approach

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)panTableView:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)pan{
    if (pan.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        int curr=currentPage;

        if (pan==self.panGestureLeft)
        {
            // user dragged towards the right

                CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
                transition.duration = 0.35;
                transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
                transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
                transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromRight;
                transition.delegate = self;
                [scrollview.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];


        }
        else if (pan==self.panGestureRight)
        {
            // user dragged towards the left

                CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
                transition.duration = 0.35;
                transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
                transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
                transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromLeft;
                transition.delegate = self;
                [scrollview.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];


        }



}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Implement Horizontal Table Scrolling

Create a TableView and transform the table

```
self.horizontalTableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI * 0.5);
```

Then, you apply the transform in reverse on the content inside the cell.

```
CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5)
```

If you want, you can then put it into another TableView inside a custom UITableViewCell, and have a vertical table of horizontal tables.

You get all the benefits of Native Scrolling

See this Tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2